# Create indexed array of filtered and trimmed elements

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, trim, reindex

I need to change the index of array after array filtering and trimming white spaces.

```
 $officials_arr= $this->input->post('officials'); 
  $officials = array_filter(array_map('trim', $officials_arr));
  print_r($officials);
```

**Desired output:**

```
(
    [0] => off1
    [1] => off2
    [2] => off3
)
```

**But I got output as :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => off1
    [1] => off2
    [3] => off3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using: `$officials = array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $officials_arr)));` (...which by the way will remove all null, false-y, zero-ish values from your array -- this is the greedy default behavior of `array_filter()`), I recommend that you generate the desired output in a more reliable and efficient way using just `array_walk()` and `strlen()`.

My method will remove zero-length strings (null/false/empty), trim spaces from both sides of each value, and re-index the result array.

Input (notice I've added spaces and empty values):

```
$officials_arr = [' off1' , 'off2' , '' , 'off3 ' , null];
//           space ^      empty string^   space^    ^null
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U5fW5))

```
$result = [];
array_walk(
    $officials,
    function($v) use (&$result) {
        $v = trim((string) $v);
        if (strlen($v)) {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }
);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'off1',
  1 => 'off2',
  2 => 'off3',
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_values`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$officials = array_values($officials);
```